# How to use a python api on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c

There is an "[Unofficial Plurk API in Python](http://code.google.com/p/plurkapipy/)".
[Plurk](http://www.plurk.com/) is a twitter-like website.

Can I use the API(python) from Objective-C? Or i have to port them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I see it, one option is to try this [this](http://www.saurik.com/id/5).

Alternatively, [ths plurk api](http://code.google.com/p/plurkapipy/source/browse/trunk/plurkapi.py) (which is really more of a python-automated abstraction than an API) isn't very big and is unlikely to take very long to port. Apart from being exceptionally simple code. The author's done all the legwork, defining urls and associated functions and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's iPhone developer license prohibits applications that use interpreted code. So, python is out, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone SDK will not allow you to run any Python code.  You need to convert it to C, C++, Objective-C or ObjectiveC++.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Plurk has an official API now, and I wrote an Objective-C library to connect to Plurk. Maybe you are interested to give it a try.

http://github.com/zonble/ObjectivePlurk

Answer (score -6):

Unfortunately, you can only do what Apple allows you to do (they are VERY controlling).  However, if you jail break your device (this violates your usage agreement with Apple) you can do many, many things with what I consider to be an amazing device (unfortunatly, Apple limits it's true possibilities).